# Why can I replace the underlying implementation after extracting the interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, junit, nunit

the following is the original text of the book 《The Art of Unit Testing, Second Edition》:
**Extract an interface to allow replacing underlying implementation**

- In this technique, you need to break out the code that touches the filesystem into a separate class. **That way you can easily distinguish it and later replace the call to that class from your tests (as was shown in figure 3.3)**. This first listing shows the places where you need to change the code.

*Listing 3.1 Extracting a class that    touches the filesystem and calling it*

```
public bool IsValidLogFileName(string fileName)
{
 FileExtensionManager mgr =
 new FileExtensionManager();
 return mgr.IsValid(fileName);
}
class FileExtensionManager
 {
 public bool IsValid(string fileName)
 {
 //read some file here
 }
 }
```

- Next, you can tell your class under test that instead of using the concrete FileExtensionManager class, it will deal with some form of ExtensionManager, without knowing its concrete implementation. In.NET, this could be accomplished by either using a base class or an interface that FileExtensionManager would extend.The next listing shows the use of a new interface in your design to make it more testable. Figure 3.4 showed a diagram of this implementation.

*Listing 3.2 Extracting an interface from a known class*

```
public class FileExtensionManager : IExtensionManager
 {
 public bool IsValid(string fileName)
 {
 ...
 }
 }
public interface IExtensionManager
 {
 bool IsValid (string fileName);
 }
//the unit of work under test:
public bool IsValidLogFileName(string fileName)
{
 IExtensionManager mgr =
 new FileExtensionManager();
 return mgr.IsValid(fileName);
 }
```

- You create an interface with one IsValid (string) method and make FileExtensionManager implement that interface. It still works exactly the same way, only now you can replace the “real” manager with your own “fake” manager, which you’ll create later to support your test.You still haven’t created the stub extension manager, so let’s create that right now.It’s shown in the following listing

---

**Question:**
I don’t understand why adding an interface makes it easier to distinguish and replace class calls later？ Is this question in the scope of design patterns? Should I learn some design patterns to better understand this question?

Comment: So you can replace it with `NetworkExtensionManager` or `FakeExtensionManager` without changing existing implementation for your code if needed.

Comment: @Orifjon I still don't understand, what benefits does adding an interface bring? Are you referring to 'it' as IExtensionManager?

Comment: **That is** the benefit. You can make your code unit testable. You can break out a portion of the code and just "assume" that it worked as expected or that it failed in a certain predictable way (because you told it to). That way you can test if the rest of the code behaves as you want / need it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don’t understand why adding an interface makes it easier to distinguish and replace class calls later？

That's an understandable confusion, given the limited example. The `IsValidLogFileName` method is still tightly coupled to the `FileExtensionManager` because it's calling its constructor.

In both the first and second example, you'd need to change one line of code if you wanted to change to a different type of extension manager. So it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

> Is this question in the scope of design patterns? Should I learn some design patterns to better understand this question?

Yes. Look into *Dependency Injection*. If `IsValidLogFileName` used an `IExtensionManager` object that was given to it, rather than creating a `new FileExtensionManager()` directly, then you would totally eliminate the reference to FileExtensionManager from its code.

You could replace the `FileExtensionManager` with a `BlobExtensionManager` or a `FakeExtensionManager` or an `EmptyExtensionManager` by simply passing a different object in. Your method's code wouldn't have to change at all!

You could write unit tests that use a *mock* `IExtensionManager` to specify what `IsValid` should return for different values, to verify that `IsValidLogFileName` behaves the way it should behave in a variety of circumstances.

Using an interface the way it's given in the example is just taking *one step* closer to decoupling yourself from implementation details. You won't see the full benefits until you can remove the implementation reference more completely from your method and its class.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The author recommended reading 《Dependency Injection in .NET》(Manning Publications, 2011) by Mark Seeman in the book. Are books like this quite advanced in terms of design pattern knowledge? Considering that I have no prior knowledge of any design patterns, should I start with some introductory books on design patterns before diving into learning about Dependency Injection?

Comment: Read what you are currently interested in. If you find something you don't know yet or don't understand, make a little break out turn and come back. Almost everything has something else "you should know first". But you need to start _somewhere_.

Comment: @Fildor I realize that I might lack some background knowledge because I still don't understand after reading the response. However, I am not sure if the missing knowledge is related to 'design patterns'. I hope to leverage your expertise to determine whether understanding the above content requires a lot of knowledge related to design patterns.

Comment: _" I am not sure if the missing knowledge is related to 'design patterns'"_ - I really don't think so. Understanding interfaces is one of the basic OOP concepts and _should_ be understood before tackling (OOP-related) design patterns. If you don't understand what an interface does, most OOP-Design-Patterns will be just greek to you.

Comment: @bokabokaboka: Stack Overflow isn't supposed to be used to request recommendations for libraries, books, etc. But I have read that one and felt like it was very approachable and pragmatic. There are also plenty of articles, youtube videos, etc. on the topic. Good design patterns tend to support one another, so there's not really a specific order in which you should learn them.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thank you for your response and reminder. I was just trying to confirm whether my issue was due to a lack of certain knowledge and did not need specific book or library recommendations. If there is anything that indeed violates Stack Overflow's rules, please let me know, and I will remove or modify the relevant content.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason to inherit from interface is when you expose your methods in API then the implementation logic won't be exposed but rather only the method definition will be seen by the API user.